# Show same item only once in drop down list?

Tags: php, html

I have the following drop down list, that has a common item 'a'. This item is shown two times in output, but it want to have it only once. Can anybody help me?

```
<select name="">
<option value="a">a</option>

<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>

 </select>
```

My code is

```
 <select name="brand" id="brand" class="txtfld" >
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <?php
           $country_sql="SELECT DISTINCT(brand) FROM customer where status='A' and brand<>''";
           $result_country=executequery($country_sql);

           while($country_array=ms_stripslashes(mysql_fetch_array($result_country)))
           {
                $sel_con=($country_array['brand']==$_REQUEST['brand'])? " selected='selected'" : " ";

                $brand=$country_array['brand'];
                $brand2=explode('|',$brand);
                if(count($brand2)<2)
                {
                     ?><option value="<?=$brand;?>" ><?=$brand;?></option><?php
                }
                else
                {
                     for($i=0;$i<count($brand2);$i++)
                     {
                          ?><option value="<?=$brand2[$i];?>" ><?=$brand2[$i];?></option><?php
                     }
                }
           }
      ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: just remove one `<option value="a">a</option>` from html if its static content.

Comment: How is that menu generated?

Comment: these content taken from database

Comment: Ok can we see your code which gets this content from database and generates the menu?

Comment: Contents are a,b,c,a|b|d,p

Comment: So i have repated values.

Comment: You must show the PHP code that generates this menu...

Comment: Just get the unique values using DB query.!!

Comment: I had updated my code,plz check it

Comment: when u post a question please add required data so that people can understand it. eg: the code that is generating the above `<select>` box. it can be anything , a `query` a block of `foreach` code . so that people can help you better and quick

Comment: ok,but my problem is same repatedly shows the same item,i got out put with rtepated items.

Comment: I completely agree that you should get them in an unique way from the DB query. I think that array_unique can have some issue with big amounts of data, I don't remember what was the command but I had a problem before in php 5.3 I think. You can also have an array with the values that you already set in to the html string, if that value is already in that array you shouldn't "paint" it again. Also I think that there is a port of the underscore library to PHP, it shouldn't be necessary has PHP has a lot of array handlers but if you already used underscore in js, it could be easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_unique()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) which will keep only unique values of your array :

```
$brand2 = explode('|',$brand);
$brand2 = array_unique($brand2);
```

Comment: What do you have exactly in $country_array['brand'] ? And what is the result of array_unique() ?

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

Try :

```
$new_array = array();
while($country_array=ms_stripslashes(mysql_fetch_array($result_country)))
       {
           $brand=$country_array['brand'];
           $brand2=explode('|',$brand);
           $NewArray = array_unique (array_merge ($NewArray, $brand2));
       }
```

Now you have all unique value in array, loop through to show the list.

**NOTE:** It might be a overhead if you have big data.